# Seeking QGIS equivalent to Path Distance of ArcMap

Tags: qgis, distance

I am a university student and, in my University, the professors use and explain ArcGIS Desktop but I want to also learn QGIS.

I do "Path Distance" in ArcMap with the following parameters:

- Input raster or feature source data: Network (a layer with 6 points)
- Output distance raster: Network_dist.tif
- Input surface raster (optional): Bythometry.tif
- Max distance (optional): 9999999999999999999

How can I do this in QGIS?

The case is that:

We have 6 points and we want a raster with minimum distance from any of that points.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: @PolyGeo Ok! I understand. I am trying to find where is "Path Distance" in QGIS and I am also failed on that. But I say that in the question.

Comment: You don't say what raster processing tools in QGIS you have researched/tried.

Comment: @PolyGeo Why raster? Source layer is not raster. Is a .shp with 6 points. Output layer is raster. I tried many raster, but mostly vector, processing tools to find something which seems correct, but I found nothing. Also I install GRASS and SAGA plugins because some google research lead me to this. But I found nothing. So, because I am 40 years old and there is no need to prove to you that I don't want my exercise solved from people on the internet, please don't test me.
If you know the question tell me. If not don't, don't tell me.

Comment: [Path Distance](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/path-distance.htm) (the tool you said you were seeking a QGIS equivalent for) is part of ArcGIS Pro's and ArcMap's Spatial Analyst extension, and that's for raster processing.

Comment: You can use vector data as input, but from the docs - "*When the input source data is a feature class, the source locations are converted internally to a raster before performing the analysis.*"

Comment: Look for [r.cost](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/r.cost.html) in the GRASS/Raster Processing Toolbox in QGIS.

Comment: @user2856 So: Unit Cost Layer: Bythometry.tif, starting point: Network, cummulative cost: Network_dist.tif. It says negative cell value at row 114.